# Thermodynamic formulation of pefect fluid with spin

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, gravity, statistical-mechanics, angular-momentum

The spin phenomena in an asymmetric spin-related Einstein-Cartan candidate solution is due to microscopic spin of small volumes of a  globally "ordinary" perfect fluid.

The only description I have seen is:

$$S_{\mu \nu} + S_{\nu \mu}=0$$

And a constraint relating the spin to the fluid acceleration.

So I can just choose anything for the non vanishing axial vector, to represent the spin vector distribution? I don't fully get it.

**How does one go about giving a statistical formulation of this strictly microscopic angular degree of freedom?**

Comment: You should add that the spin tensor should be orthogonal to the local 4-velocity of the fluid : $S_{\mu \nu} \, u^{\nu} = 0$.  That constraint says that $S_{i 0}  = 0$ in the rest frame of a fluid element (spin is a spacelike property).

Comment: OP prefers explicit formulae, before putting Dirac things in there. :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to know.  You should make your question more precise.

Comment: @Someone I have edited with the punch line

Comment: If you want to see how to arrive from microscopic  description of point particles with spin to a continuous fluid medium by averaging, have a look at a book "Relativistic theory of spinning fluids", by Halbwachs (pdf [here](http://www.neo-classical-physics.info/uploads/3/0/6/5/3065888/halbwachs_-_book_main_body.pdf)), but it is for a flat space. For equations of spinning fluid in Einstein–Cartan theory have a look, for example, [here](https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/4/6/021)

Comment: @A.V.S. Is there a chance that the  flat space analysis be sufficient to make the leap to Einstein-Cartan context?

Comment: Yes of course, but there is also a possibility of nonminimal coupling with gravity, which would not be captured by a flat space calculations.